# ideal code/folder structure for CRUD app

Tags: angularjs

As part of learning angular i’ve decided to create a simple bug tracker app using ng-boilerplate as a starting point as I like their approach to folder structure. I’ve got the auth down and have moved onto the "members area” which lists all the users projects and allows them to create new projects and to eventually add bugs to each project.

I’m having a bit of an analysis paralysis in regards to structuring the code the “angular way”. So far I have :

```
- member
— add-project
—— add.js
—— add.tpl.html
- member.tpl.html
- member.js
```

inside member.js I have a memberctrl which lists the users projects and adds a new project, calling a factory called ProjectsService (also sitting in member.js) to do both. The ProjectsService currently has two methods, query() and add() although obviously this would grow to include update, delete etc.

The add.js in the add-project folder seems a bit redundant at the moment, but i’m worried that the member controller is going to grow (editing projects, adding bugs, editing bugs etc) so what would be an ideal structure going forward? Should I have a separate addProjectCtrl inside add.js solely for adding a project? Should I remove add() from ProjectsService and move it into its own factory in add.js as well?

Code for member.js is as follows

```
.controller('MemberCtrl', function MemberCtrl($scope, $location,ProjectsService) {
        $scope.projects = [];
        $scope.refresh = function () {
            ProjectsService.query()
                .then(function (data) {
                    $scope.projects = data;
                });
        };


    $scope.addProject = function (project) {
        ProjectsService.add(project).then(function (data) {
            $scope.projects = data;
            $location.path("/member");
        });
    };


    //is this just going to get bigger and bigger?

    $scope.refresh();
})

.factory('ProjectsService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        query: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/api/get-projects')
                .success(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    deferred.reject(data);
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        },
        add: function (project) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http.post('/api/create-project', project)
                .success(function (data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    deferred.reject(data);
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        }

    };
}])
```

and code for add.js

```
angular.module( 'ngBoilerplate.member.add-project', [
    'ui.router',
    'placeholders',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngBoilerplate.config',
    'ngBoilerplate.member'
])


    .config(function config( $stateProvider,USER_ROLES ) {
        $stateProvider.state( 'member.add-project', {
            url: '/add-project',
            views: {
                "main": {
                    templateUrl: 'member/add-project/add.tpl.html'
                }
            },
            data:{ pageTitle: 'Add Project'

            }
        });
    })


;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [official angular-seed project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), or [Yeoman angular generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) which will give you a barebone structure for start your angular projects.

A generally good practice is to split into different files your Controllers / Services / Directives.

For a more detailed code guide, read the popular [angular-style-guide](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide).
Extracted from it, here is an example of structure :

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── home
│   │   │   ├── FirstCtrl.js
│   │   │   └── SecondCtrl.js
│   │   └── about
│   │       └── ThirdCtrl.js
│   ├── directives
│   │   ├── home
│   │   │   └── directive1.js
│   │   └── about
│   │       ├── directive2.js
│   │       └── directive3.js
│   ├── filters
│   │   ├── home
│   │   └── about
│   └── services
│       ├── CommonService.js
│       ├── cache
│       │   ├── Cache1.js
│       │   └── Cache2.js
│       └── models
│           ├── Model1.js
│           └── Model2.js
├── partials
├── lib
└── test
```